# 500 - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string error After making the site multilanguage

Tags: joomla-2.5, multilingual

I have a Joomla 2.5 site that until yesterday I had only one language installed, but I made it multilanguage.

After that Im getting this error on specific pages:

> 500 - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (vendredi 22 avril 2016) at position 0 (v): The timezone could not be found in the database

Searching at google I found out this is a common bug on Joomla 3+ . Most common problem is the dirs of **tmp** and **logs** at **configuration.php**.

I checked and both the dirs are correct and they exist. I checked the permissions too and they are also correct.
I unpublished the **Admin Tools** component because someone said it could be the problem, but nothing changed.
I set the date.timezone in my php.ini that had no value before.
I don't get any error at my error_log considering this issue so I cant debug further.

I'm using Joomla 2.5.28.Has anyone met something like that before ?

Comment: Did you try following the instruction [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16632673/1362108) get the get the full path to the match against you log/tmp paths?

Comment: @Lodder Yes. I pasted the path I took from that script.

Comment: I believe this is not Joomla overall, but particular pages issue. try to understand what components, modules and plugins are at work, try to load page with ?tmpl=component - and go from this point to investigate further.